# How to get the original error from a failing JUnit test?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I'm writing a JUnit test for a database application.   The test fails when run against my testing (HSQLDB) database.   The error message I would *like* to get is this error message, which is the actual exception and which I understand completely:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Violation of unique constraint SYS_PK_47: duplicate value(s) for column(s) SECONDARY_ACCOUNT_ID
```

However, this information does not appear *anyplace* in the stack trace of the test failure.   Instead, the error seems to be filtered through Spring, Hibernate and JDBC and I get this completely useless, information-free "JDBC exception":

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [insert into CAACCTS (CREDIT_APPLICATION_ID, PRIMARY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SECONDARY_ACCOUNT_ID, SECONDARY_ACCT_NAME, SECONDARY_ADDY_ID, SECONDARY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Could not execute JDBC batch update; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:651)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:516)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy26.save(Unknown Source)
    [snip]
```

I have already set the Log4J logging all the way up to TRACE without success.  Can anyone tell me how to grab this original error (not just in this failed test, but for future tests as well?)

I'm using HSQLDB, Spring 3, Hibernate 3.6 and JPA 2.  My IDE is Intellij IDEA.  The project is Maven-based.   I will be happy to provide additional details if needed to help me diagnose this.

Answer (score 0):

One method of drilling down to the root exception is something like this:

```
catch(Throwable t)
{
    while(t.getCause != null)
    {
        t = t.getCause();
    }
    t.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Comment: Nope, I just get the original error back.  Someplace in the bowels of Hibernate or HSQLDB it's catching that error and throwing a new one.

Comment: hmm, that's annoying.  I'm not aware of a way of retrieving an exception that hasn't been passed up as a cause if your trace logging on org.springframework.orm.hibernate3 and org.hsqldb isn't returning anything.  You might try looking at the hibernate source code where the error originated (`at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:651)`) and see if that gives you any clues

Comment: I'm afraid that's what I'm going to have to do.   Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tried triggering the same HSQLDB error using straight JDBC? How does the exception look in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to catch **org.hibernate.JDBCException** or check if Hibernate exception is an instance of **org.hibernate.JDBCException**:

```
} catch (JDBCException e) {
    logger.warn("jdbc problem", e.getSQLException());
}
```

or...

```
if (e instanceof JDBCException) {
    SQLException sqle = ((JDBCException) e).getSQLException();
}
```

Normally hibernate JDBCException contain related DB specific JDBC exception an you can retrieve that using getSQLException() method